# The URL I test in my browser is different than what comes back on svcutil.exe

Tags: wcf

When I enter my ECF Service URL

```
https://MYDOMAIN.COM/Service/MYSVCNAME.svc
```

Page comes back with:

> To test this service, you will need to create a client and use it to
>   call the service. You can do this using the svcutil.exe tool from the
>   command line with the following syntax:
>
> svcutil.exe
>   https://ANOTHER_DOMAIN_IN_THE_COMPANY.COM/Service/MYSVCNAME.svc

I'm a little confused what could cause this 'different domain'.

Ed

Comment: Adding site binding in IIS solved my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding hostheader, site binding in IIS solved my issue